# iOS CoreBluetooth CBErrorDomain=8 while trying to implement HID specification

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I keep getting

```
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=8 "The specified UUID is not allowed
for this operation." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The specified
UUID is not allowed for this operation.}
```

While trying to implement the services listed on this page https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.human_interface_device.xml

I can't find any information on what the error means beyond the short description above. The error happens when I attempt to start advertising so it doesn't give any insight into whether its the service itself or one of the characteristic.

What is the meaning of the error and what can I do to rectify it?

I found this snippet in a related question:

> Note that Apple does prevent iOS applications from publishing HID over
>   GATT but I assume that limitation is not present on OS X.

So I'm hoping that's not true.

I will add that I got internal consistency errors when I tried to add the descriptors laid out in the above spec to the characteristics, which I thought was odd.

I went through and removed the characteristics one by one until the error went away. These are the offending characteristic UUIDs:

```
uuid: "2A4A", // HID Information
uuid: "2A33", // Boot Mouse Input Report
uuid: "2A4B", // Report Map
uuid: "2A4D", // Report 
uuid: "2A4E", // Protocol Mode
```

I'm adding these characteristics to a service with UUID 1812, as per the HID spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it does appear that Apple prevents the HID service from working on an iPhone acting as a peripheral. I used LightBlue to create a test peripheral and it would only advertise when not using the HID 0x1812 UUID. This is very upsetting.

Answer (score 3):

We have stumbled upon this issue as well. Apple blocks some of the standardised BLE services on iOS and even macOS (HID over GATT in particular). We had to build our own BLE device based on a Nordic Semiconductor NRF51 chipset to overcome these restrictions. Less than ideal I can say...